# How can I add record name in a JavaScript popup before deletion in Asp.net C# code

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, .net, gridview

I have a following column in my GridView in Asp.net Code. This is column containing a delete icon against all of the records in my GridView. What I want to do is to add the name of the record in a JavaScript confirmation popup which I have already implemented.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GVCities" CssClass="Gview" HeaderStyle-BorderStyle="None" runat="server"
AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="White" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="Black"
GridLines="Horizontal" >
    <Columns>

        ...

        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="imgbtnDelete" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("CityId")%>'
                ImageUrl="~/images/delete_icon.png" ToolTip="Delete" 
                OnClick="imgbtnDelete_OnClick" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this city?');" />
            </ItemTemplate>
            <ItemStyle CssClass="GVItems" />
            <HeaderStyle CssClass="GVHeader" HorizontalAlign="right" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
        </asp:TemplateField>

    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

I want to display the City Name in the JavaScript Delete confirmation dialog.
I have tried the code at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb428868.aspx) but couldn't be able to get the desired result.

### Expected Result

Are you sure you want to delete **Amsterdam** city?

instead of

Are you sure you want to delete **this** city?

Comment: have you tried this way 
<%# Eval("reocrdName")%> in confirm box line

Comment: Yes I have already tried it but it produce an error on page load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the `onClientClick` event from your client side code and `DataKeyNames="Cities"` attribute and give it your "Cities" column name. Use `OnRowDataBound="GVCities_OnRowDataBound"` to bound your dialog with all the rows on page load. So whenever the user clicks on the delete button or delete image, the respective confirmation dialog will appear before deletion.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GVCities" CssClass="Gview" HeaderStyle-BorderStyle="None" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="White" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="Black" GridLines="Horizontal" DataKeyNames="Cities" OnRowDataBound="GVCities_OnRowDataBound" >
<Columns>

    ...

    <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="imgbtnDelete" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("CityId")%>'
            ImageUrl="~/images/delete_icon.png" ToolTip="Delete" 
            OnClick="imgbtnDelete_OnClick" />
        </ItemTemplate>
        <ItemStyle CssClass="GVItems" />
        <HeaderStyle CssClass="GVHeader" HorizontalAlign="right" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
    </asp:TemplateField>

</Columns>
```

### At Code Behind

By using the following code, you can bound your dialog with every row on page load. Whenever user clicks on delete icon, it will ask for confirmation containing the city name as you are expecting.

```
protected void GVCities_OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {

            ImageButton imgbtnDelete = e.Row.FindControl("imgbtnDelete") as ImageButton;
            imgbtnDelete.OnClientClick = "return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete " +  
                                         GVCities.DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex]["Cities"].ToString() + " city?');";
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
       ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Try Following

```
 OnClientClick='<%# "confirm(" + Eval("LocationId") + ");" %>'
```

Comment: see my edit, test if it renders the output, your most likely have to put the content within  <%%> blocks.

Comment: I got this error after using your seggested code **Parser Error Message:** The server tag is not well formed.